# Rails ignores columns from second table when using .select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

By example:

```
r = Model.arel_table
s = SomeOtherModel.arel_table
Model.select(r[:id], s[:othercolumn].as('othercolumn')).
joins(:someothermodel)
```

Will product the sql:

```
`SELECT `model`.`id`, `someothermodel`.`othercolumn` AS othercolumn FROM `model` INNER JOIN `someothermodel` ON `model`.`id` = `someothermodel`.`model_id`
```

Which is correct. However, when the models are loaded, the attribute `othercolumn` is ignored because it is not an attribute of `Model`.

It's similar to eager loading and `includes`, but I don't want all columns, only the one specified so `include` is no good.

There must be an easy way of getting columns from other models? I'd preferably have the items return as instances of `Model` than simple arrays/hashes

Comment: are Model and OtherModel related in any way?

Comment: Yes, `Model` has one `SomeOtherModel`

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/03/10/rails-3-arel,arel_table,-and-squeel/).  I think the gem that's mentioned ([squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `select` with `joins` or `includes`, you will be returned an `ActiveRecordRelation`.  This `ActiveRecordRelation` is composed of only the objects of the  class which you use to call `select` on.  The selected columns from the joined models are added to the objects returned.  Because these attributes are not `Model`'s attribute they don't show up when you inspect these objects, and I believe this is the primary reason for confusion.

You could try this out in your rails console:

```
> result = Model.select(r[:id], s[:othercolumn].as('othercolumn')).joins(:someothermodel)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Model id: 1>]>

# "othercolumn" is not shown in the result but doing the following will yield correct result
> result.first.othercolumn
=> "myothercolumnvalue"
```