# Rails model ignoring additional specifically selected colums from other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is closely related to [Rails ignores columns from second table when using .select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431527/rails-ignores-columns-from-second-table-when-using-select), however that question doesn't go deep enough.

As per the above question, I have a complex query being run from one of my ActiveRecord Models which generates a kind of 'report'.  It is basically a giant table of the primary Model's attributes as well as a few other attributes from related tables.

- **The query itself, works.** I have verified that the resulting SQL executes correctly and when pasted into a SQL terminal I get the results (and columns I want). Unfortunately there is proprietary information in the models that I can't share here, and the Query is too complex to obfuscate.  But To give an idea of what I am doing, this is the start of my ActiveRecord Query: `permits = Permit.select('*').joins("LEFT JOIN crosstab (' ....`
- I have pasted the ActiveRecord Query (above) into the Rails console and not only does it execute perfectly; but the additional attributes (not asssigned to any model or association in my app) can be queried, just fine - exactly what I want:

  `>> permits.first.applicant_name`
  `"Gordon Ramsay"`

The problem is that when I execute the code in the rails app (executed from the browser) I can access the attributes of each permit and its associated models ok, but the additional selects on permit raise a NoMethodError.

I cannot understand why the Rails console will let me plug the commands in and work, but when I run the same code in only of my application's methods, it raises an error.

The question above seems to deal with this closely, and the accepted answer suggests trying something out in the console; but why would the console and the Rails app itself deal with this same code differently (since I am under the assumption that the Rails console **is** an instance of the Rails application?

Does anyone know:

1. Is my assumption about the ActiveRecordRelation omitting the non-model attributes correct?
2. Why does the Rails console allow me to do this query and call the 'extra' selected columns but Rails will not.
3. Is there a way I can do what I need to do - perhaps creating a proxy object or casting the Permit model to some other ActiveRecord Object that doesn't 'ignore/drop' the extra attributes from the select?

Comment: What you are doing should work. I have many queries in my project for which I get back additional attributes on the records queried, and it works the same from the console as it does from within the Rails app. Try using `select('permits.*, your_other_model_pluralized.applicant_name')` followed by the rest of your SQL and then see if the `applicant_name` attribute sticks. If not, I suspect there is another problem in your code that you are not noticing--for example, perhaps you are reloading `permits` before you call for `permits.first.applicant_name`.

Comment: I've run permits.first.attributes.keys and the additional attributes aren't there, despite being called in the select.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it doesn't make sense. Rails does let you do this. Have you tried running a debugger and checking `permits.first.attributes` immediately after your SQL executes?