# How to join the Users table to a list of 100 Ranking Records to avoid 100+ extra user queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ranking model with the following fields:

```
Ranking.rb
  t.string "job_type"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "ranking"
  t.integer "total_ranked"
  t.integer "points"
```

This table is populated by a Background job w ~100 records. I then want to have my API query and return the results of the records stored in ranking like so:

```
@rankings = Ranking.where(job_type: 'all_users').order('id ASC').select('id, user_id, ranking, points')
```

The problem is I do not have the associated User information per each ranking. Per each ranking, I want to user the user_id to find the User and get User.displayName, User.photo_url.

If I loop through @rankings and make a user query for each record that will be an extra 100+ queries.

How can I take @rankings and somehow include the associated user fields (User.displayName, User.photo_url)? Ideally with less database queries.

Comment: you can use `includes`, something like: `Ranking.includes(:user)` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [active record :joins method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). Assuming the `users` table also has a field called `id` and not `user_id`, this should work:

```
Ranking
  .select('rankings.id, rankings.ranking, rankings.points, users.displayName, users.photo_url')
  .joins('JOIN users ON rankings.user_id = users.id')
  .where(job_type: 'all_users')
  .order('id ASC')`
```

**Edit:** I couldn't find documentation for selecting values from multiple tables, just stack old overflow answers. So if that doesn't work, you could just do:

```
@rankings = Ranking.where(job_type: 'all_users').order('id ASC').select('id, user_id, ranking, points').includes(:user)
```

Which will load each `Ranking` with it's associated `User` all in one query using `includes`(which @thanh mentioned in his comment, he linked the docs too which are worth checking out). You can then loop through the ratings and get the `displayName` and `photo_url` without making extra database calls.

**edit 2 :)**
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431527/rails-ignores-columns-from-second-table-when-using-select) my first answer should work, but since `:select` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object, it will only contain objects of the class you call `:select` on (in our case `Ranking`). The `User` columns will be available on those `Ranking` objects. It also looks like we'll need to alias those user columns, so something like this:

```
@rankings = Ranking
  .select('rankings.id, rankings.ranking, rankings.points, users.displayName as user_display_name, users.photo_url as user_photo_id')
  .joins('JOIN users ON rankings.user_id = users.id')
  .where(job_type: 'all_users')
  .order('id ASC')`
```

then access them like:

`@rankings.first.user_photo_url #=> "https://flikr.com/whatever"`

Comment: the 2nd idea `@rankings = Ranking.where(job_type: 'all_users').order('id ASC').select('id, user_id, ranking, points').includes(:users)` errors w `Association named 'users' was not found on Ranking; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: @AnApprentice yup, should be `includes(:user)`